# Implementing state pattern with Graph data structure

Tags: java, oop, graph, reflection, state-pattern

I am currently trying to implement an application where there are about 10 states. Unlike traditional state pattern where there is only 1 link to a different state from one state, I want it to be more like a directed graph where one state can have multiple edges to different states.

Example: I have states 1-10 ( vertexes).  - are the edges. These can be the possible state transitions.

1-2, 1-3, 1-6
2-3, 2-9
3-5
4-3
5-2, 5-3, 5-4
6-3, 6-4,6-7, 6-9
... And so on

Each states are classes, and each edges (the -) are methods. For example:

`Class State1 {
    public void goToState2() ;
    public void goToState3() ;
    public void goToState6() ;
}`

`Class State2 {
    public void goToState3() ;
    public void goToState9() ;
}`
...

I could think of reflection and bunch of switch statements to solve this problem, but I think I could also apply state pattern or come up with a more elegant solution here but I am absolutely stuck.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you need these methods?  "Going to another state" is along the lines of `context.setState(new State2());` in response to some event or condition.  What is the actual problem here?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  this was another question I asked before that has more detailed description of what I am trying to get at! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938433/state-method-graph-traversal-in-java-design

Answer (score 0):

As there is state transition graph involved, there is need to maintain adjacency and  define transition criteria. This criteria can be common for all nodes ( For example transition from one node to another is dictated by cost of transition) or it can be customized per node (For example on some node transition happens based on cost while for other transition happens based on node type).

```
class ExecutionParameters;
class IState;
using SPState = std::shared_ptr<IState>;
using SPStates = std::list<SPState>;
class _declspec(novtable) IState
{
public:
    virtual void Execute(Context& context, const ExecutionParameters& params) = 0;
    virtual SPStates GetAdjacentStates() const noexcept = 0;
};

class _declspec(novtable) ITransitionCriteria
{
public:
    virtual SPState ComputeNextState() const = 0;
};

class CostBasedTransition : public ITransitionCriteria
{
public:
    SPState ComputeNextState() const override
    {
         // Find min transition cost adjacent node
    }
};
using SPTransitionCriteria = std::shared_ptr<ITransitionCriteria>;

class StateNode : public IState
{
public:
    StateNode(int id, SPTransitionCriteria spTransitionCriteria) :m_id(id), m_spTransitionCriteria(spTransitionCriteria)
    {}
    StateNode(int id) :StateNode(id, nullptr)//Choose default transition criteria//)
    {}

    void Execute(Context& context, const ExecutionParameters& params) override
    {
        // Perform action

        // Update context state
        context.SetState(m_spTransitionCriteria->GetNextState());
    }

    SPStates GetAdjacentStates() const noexcept
    {
        return m_spAdjacentStates;
    }

    void AddAjacentState(SPState spState)
    {
    }

    void RemoveAjacentState(int stateId)
    {
    }
private:
    int m_id;
    SPStates m_spAdjacentStates;
    SPTransitionCriteria m_spTransitionCriteria;
};

class Context
{
public:
    void Execute(const ExecutionParameters& params)
    {
        m_spState->Execute(*this, params);
    }

    void SetState(SPState& spState)
    {
        m_spState = spState;
    }
private:
    SPState m_spState;
};
```